# qr function in R and matlab

Tags: r, matlab, qr-decomposition

I have a question about converting a matlab function into R, and I was hoping that someone could help.

The standard QR decomposition used in both matlab and R is referred to as qr(). To my understanding, the standard way of performing a qr decomposition in both languages is:

Matlab:
**`[Q,R] = qr(A)`** satisfying QR=A

R:

```
z <- qr(A)
Q <- qr.Q(z)
R <- qr.R(z)
```

Both of which provide me with the same results, unfortunately, this is not what I need. What I need is this:

Matlab:
**[Q,R,e] = qr(A,0)** which produces an economy-size decomposition in which e is a permutation vector so that A(:,e) = Q*R.

R:
No clue

I have tried comparing **[Q,R,E] = qr(A)** with

```
z <- qr(A);
Q <- qr.Q(z);
R <- qr.R(z);
E <- diag(ncol(A))[z$pivot]
```

and results seem identical for variables Q and E (but different for R). So depending on the defined inputs/outputs there will be different results (which makes sense).

So my question is:
***Is there a way in R that can mimic this [Q,R,e]=qr(A,0) in Matlab?***

I have tried digging into the matlab function but it leads to a long and torturous road of endless function definitions and I was hoping for a better solution.

Any help would be much appreciated, and if I've missed something obvious, I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the difference comes down to the numerical library underlying the calculations. By default, R's `qr` function uses the (very old) [LINPACK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LINPACK) routines, but if I do

```
z <- qr(X,LAPACK=T)
```

then R uses LAPACK and the results seem to match MATLAB's (which is probably also using LAPACK underneath). Either way we see the expected relationship with `X`:

```
z <- qr(X,LAPACK=F)
all.equal(X[,z$pivot], qr.Q(z)%*%qr.R(z), check.attributes=FALSE)
# [1] TRUE

z <- qr(X,LAPACK=T)
all.equal(X[,z$pivot], qr.Q(z)%*%qr.R(z), check.attributes=FALSE)
# [1] TRUE
```