# Differences in QR decomposition of complex matrix in R and Matlab

Tags: r, matlab, matrix, complex-numbers, qr-decomposition

With the below matrix `A`, I get different matrices for R in its QR decomposition between [R] and Matlab. (The Q's are different as well, of course.)

```
A <- structure(c(1+0i, -0.75+0.75i, 0+0i, 0+0i, 1+0i, -0.75+0.75i, 
1+0i, -1.5+1.5i, 0-1i), .Dim = c(3L, 3L))

QR <- qr(A)
Q <- qr.Q(A)
R <- qr.R(QR)
R
            [,1]                  [,2]                   [,3]
[1,] -2.54951+0i  0.8825226+0.8825226i -1.27475488+0.0000000i
[2,]  0.00000+0i -0.7531983+0.0000000i -0.49787685+0.4978768i
[3,]  0.00000+0i  0.0000000+0.0000000i -0.06509446+0.0000000i
```

Whereas with Matlab:

```
[Q,R] = qr(A);
R =
  -1.4577 + 0.0000i   0.5145 + 0.5145i  -2.2295 - 0.0000i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i  -1.2632 + 0.0000i   0.8732 - 0.8732i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0679 + 0.0000i
```

Checking the decomposition from R software, I have to reorder the R matrix's columns to recreate my original matrix `A` using `Q %*% R[, QR$pivot]`, but this of course destroys the upper triangular nature of R:

```
zapsmall(Q %*% R[, QR$pivot])
            [,1]        [,2]      [,3]
[1,]  1.00+0.00i  0.00+0.00i  1.0+0.0i
[2,] -0.75+0.75i  1.00+0.00i -1.5+1.5i
[3,]  0.00+0.00i -0.75+0.75i  0.0-1.0i
```

Whereas with Matlab, a straight `Q * R` works:

```
Q * R
ans = 
   1.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   1.0000 + 0.0000i
  -0.7500 + 0.7500i   1.0000 + 0.0000i  -1.5000 + 1.5000i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.7500 + 0.7500i   0.0000 - 1.0000i
```

I realise that a QR decomposition is not unique, but I need to get an upper triangular R matrix just like in Matlab which I can use subsequently *without rearranging its columns*, such that `Q %*% R = A`.

Any suggestions in the R software on how I might achieve this?

Update:
A suggestion was made that question [may be answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47596598/qr-function-in-r-and-matlab), but that answer will only work with *real* matrices, whereas my query is for *complex*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [qr function in R and matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47596598/qr-function-in-r-and-matlab)

Comment: I did see that, but I’m not sure it applies here because the lapack option seems to work only for real matrices, not complex?

Comment: You're right, I missed that.